# form_for action has .id appended to URL during edit action - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where when I submit during an edit action has the .id appended to the post action when it shouldn't. The form works correctly during create but not update.

Here's the URL post action during edit.

http://localhost:3000/members/1/profile.1

Heres my form

```
<%= form_for([@member, @profile]) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :first_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name, {:class => "txt-field-short"} %><br /><br />
<%= f.label :last_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :last_name, {:class => "txt-field-short"} %><br /><br />
<p><%= submit_tag "Create Profile" %></p>
<% end %>
```

This is my route for this association.

```
resources :members do
  resource :profile
  resources :orders
end
```

Here's my create, edit and update actions in my profiles controller

```
def create
 @member = current_member
 @profile = @member.build_profile(params[:profile])

 respond_to do |format|
  if @profile.save
    format.html { redirect_to(member_profile_path, :notice => 'Profile was successfully     created.') }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
  end
end
end

def edit
 @member = current_member
 @profile = @member.profile
end

def update
 @member = current_member
 @profile = @member.profile
 respond_to do |format|
   if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
     format.html { redirect_to(member_profile_path(@profile), :notice => 'Your profile was successfully updated.') }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
   end
 end
end
```

What's adding the profile.id to the post action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can sometimes happen with nested singular resources. Try using a different `form_for` format:

```
form_for @profile, :url => member_profile_path(@member) do |f|
```

Comment: Right. It's treating `@profile` as the `:format` option to the url.

Comment: Could you please clarify this issue more -- like, why exactly this happens? I encountered the same problem and now having hard time trying to apply your solution.

Comment: When you have nested singular resources, the url helper doesn't need to be passed the singular resource object _because it knows there is only one object to choose from_. So e.g. `member_profile_path(@member, @profile)` should become `member_profile_path(@member)` because there is no ambiguity in which profile you're talking about (there's only one for each member). Similarly with `form_for`.